# How access context from another file

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have Assistant activity and an alertDialog function in another kotlin file. I want to create alertdialog box. But I don't know how I can call context of Assistant. Can you help me? I couldn't understand contexts.

My assistant class:

```
class AssistantActivity : GenericActivity(), SnackBarActivity {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.assistant_activity)
    }
```

My alertDialog function:

````
fun buttonClickDialog() {

            val domainArray: Array<String> = tenantNames.toTypedArray()

            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder()
            with(builder) {

                setTitle("Choose 1")
                setItems(domainArray) { dialog, which ->
                }
            }
            val alertDialog = builder.create()
            alertDialog.show()
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where your are calling buttonClickDialog() function.
My thoughts are if you are showing the AlertDialog inside AssistantActivity or in a fragment that belongs to AssistantActivity, the "activity" keyword will return the context of AssistantActivity. You can also cast it as (activity as? AssistantActivity)?.

Or, Maybe you can pass it as parameter
fun buttonClickDialog(context: Context) {
...

Comment: I am calling buttonClickDialog() function in ViewModel class. When I click login button I will see alertDialog. My login button is in ViewModel class. But ViewModel class doesn't have a context. So I can't "this" context.  What should I write for context. I hope I can tell. It's very complex :(

Comment: Do you create that viewModel in AssistantActivity?